# Problema com Primefaces executando glassfish

Tags: java, primefaces, glassfish

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação Java Web utilizando Primefaces para executar no servidor GlassFish em um servidor Windows Server 2008. 
Quando executo no meu notebook como localhost funciona perfeitamente. Então faço o deploy no servidor remoto(Windows Server) tudo corretamente. O problema é quando da minha máquina ou de qualquer outra tento acessar e nada acontece, nem erro. Se eu acessar como localhost no windows server também funciona normal.
Também realizei alguns testes com páginas jsp nesse servidor remoto e funcionou.

Alguém sabe me dizer se existem alguma configuração no servidor glassfish pra configurar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pedro, o seu problema, pela descrição, não tem nada a ver com o PrimeFaces (como você disse, acessando localmente tudo funciona).
Com as configurações padrão do GlassFish você deveria poder acessar o servidor remotamente sem problemas. 
Infelizmente não é possível fazer um diagnóstico preciso sem mais informações. Mesmo assim, seguem algumas sugestões:

- Verifique configurações de *firewall*, veja se a porta 8080 (ou a porta que você configurou) está aberta e autorizada para o GlassFish (esse é o problema boa parte das vezes).
- Se você usa um *proxy*, verifique se ele não está interferindo (ou seja, verifique que seu navegador realmente está chegando no servidor).
- Verifique se você consegue pingar o servidor.
- Verifique os *listeners*. No *Admin Console* do GlassFish cheque as configurações em `Configurations > server-config > HTTP Service > HTTP Listeners >`; os *listeners* `http-listener-1` e `http-listener-2` devem estar ouvindo em `0.0.0.0` ou no endereço do servidor.